# Max no of users in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I was working to set up SSRS as a Self Service tool for all the users in an organisation.
Is it possible to have 5000 unique users for SSRS ?
If so, can we set up row level security for each employee ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can provide row level security. By providing the individual user permissions to the database and restrict the data returned for your report.

There is no rule as to how many users you can have (I believe it is set to 32767). However depending on what they are doing, the simultaneous user connection number can get limited by your hardware specifications so to not overload your server.